QT Advance Docking system: How to lock floating docks inside window
I'm using the QT Advanced Docking System
https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/Qt-Advanced-Docking-System
which seems rather mature.
As soon as I undock my docks, they will be freely floating on the screen.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find out, how to lock a floating dock inside the borders of my window ("MDI style")
Is there any possibility to do that?
Some simple code to get started:
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <DockManager.h>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QMdiArea>

using namespace ads;

class MainWin: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWin(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWin();

private:
    CDockManager mDockManager;

};

MainWin::MainWin(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),mDockManager(this)
{
    setCentralWidget(&mDockManager);

    CDockWidget *dock=new CDockWidget("New Dock",&mDockManager);
    mDockManager.addDockWidgetFloating(dock);
}


I don't think this is possible. You can have a look at QMdiArea or DockWidgetFloatable.

A floating dock is a separated window, MDI areas use subwindows, children of the window; you cannot get both aspects, as they are incompatible by their own nature. Even assuming that you may be able to partially restrict user movement by checking the geometry in the moveEvent and resizeEvent overrides, that would be quite unreliable: what should then happen when the window is resized, possibly hiding (partially or completely) some of those docks? Besides, I'm not even sure that ADS uses spontaneous system movement/resizing for docks, which would make it even more difficult to achieve.
